# AnimatedVectorDrawable empty path to the drawable path

Tags: android, animation, svg, vector

**What I want**

I want to be able to draw a Vector Drawable from no path -> target. So for example, draw from nothing to a check mark SVG.

**What I've tried**

Here is my Vector drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:height="128dp"
    android:width="128dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24">

<path
    android:name="done"
    android:pathData="M9 16.2L4.8 12l-1.4 1.4L9 19 21 7l-1.4-1.4L9 16.2z"
    android:fillColor="#fff"
    android:strokeWidth="1"
    android:strokeLineCap="round"
    android:strokeColor="#fff"/>
```

That is just a check mark SVG.

Here is my animation (Which I know is wrong.. :( ). The path data for animating from one vector drawable to another must have the same number of path directions:

```
<objectAnimator
android:duration="3000"
android:propertyName="pathData"
android:valueFrom="0"
android:valueTo="M9 16.2L4.8 12l-1.4 1.4L9 19 21 7l-1.4-1.4L9 16.2z"
android:valueType="pathType"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
```

And the animated vector (tying together the vector + animation)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animated-vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_done">

<target
    android:animation="@animator/ic_disappear"
    android:name="opacity"/>
```

This is wrong as I noted above. How then, do I create an object animator for a SVG to animate from no path to the path I want. This animation is similar to someone drawing the drawable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, the two paths descriptions have to have the same number of commands and coordinates.  Your path is a filled shape, and you can only animate once linearly. So you can't do a two-step down-and-then-up check motion.  At least not with a single path morph.

A first simple approach would just be to start from the path start point. That happens to be at the crook of the check mark. So it doesn't look to bad.

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <path d="M0 0">
    <animate attributeName="d" attributeType="XML"
       from="M9 16.2 L 9 16.2 l 0 0 L 9 16.2 9 16.2 l 0 0 L 9 16.2z"
       to="M9 16.2 L 4.8 12 l -1.4 1.4 L 9 19 21 7 l -1.4-1.4 L 9 16.2z"
       dur="1s" fill="freeze" />
  </path>
</svg>
```

Or you could start it at the centre point of the corner:

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <path d="M0 0">
    <animate attributeName="d" attributeType="XML"
       from="M9 17.6 L 9 17.6 l 0 0 L 9 17.6 9 17.6 l 0 0 L 9 17.6z"
       to="M9 16.2 L 4.8 12 l -1.4 1.4 L 9 19 21 7 l -1.4-1.4 L 9 16.2z"
       dur="1s" fill="freeze" />
  </path>
</svg>
```

Or maybe start with the corner diamond and grow the two "arms" from there.

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <path d="M0 0">
    <animate attributeName="d" attributeType="XML"
       from="M9 16.2 L 9 16.2 l -1.4 1.4 L 9 19 l 1.4 -1.4 l -1.4-1.4 L 9 16.2z"
       to=  "M9 16.2 L 4.8 12 l -1.4 1.4 L 9 19 L 21 7     l -1.4-1.4 L 9 16.2z"
       dur="1s" fill="freeze" />
  </path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Wow, I'll try this later that is a good idea. I like the the idea of growing the two arms. I just discovered the concept of animations with SVGs a couple of days ago, so I'm really exploring. Any tips on figuring out how to parse the path string? It reads as gibberish to a certain extent to me and I want to learn more

Comment: The definitive source is the SVG spec.: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathData

Comment: @rosenthal what vector drawable did you end up creating? can you share the code?

Answer (score 0):

You may animate trimPathEnd property from 0 to 1 in duration of your choice instead of animating pathData. So change the propertyName to trimPathEnd and changing the AnimatedVectorDrawable file also suitably. The result is as if the tick is being written now.

Further, if you want a demo read the tutorial ["An Introduction to Icon Animation Techniques"](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2016/11/introduction-to-icon-animation-techniques.html). There are some interactive demo items in the body of the article.

You may also read about AnimatedVectorDrawable class in android developer site. Though trimPathEnd propertyName is not in the list, it works.